# Forward to jsp from java script method not working for browser

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.2. In my java application I am using the ExtJS calendar (I am using Eclipse Indigo IDE for developement) in one of my JSP.

Now I am getting a pop up to save the event when I click on any date in month format. But I want to display one of my custom JSP when clicked on any day on the ExtJS calendar instead of the pop up which is another JavaScript file.

So I changed in App.js file present in examples/calendar/src folder to get the required JSP. I changed in

```
showEditWindow : function(rec, animateTarget)
```

method and instead of the function body where the pop up was coming I wrote the line

```
window.navigate("my jsp path in eclipse")
```

It is working fine if I am executing the file in my Tomcat server using Eclipse browser. But if I use any other browser then the functionality is not working (i.e nothing happening when I am clicking on the date).

I am totally new to JavaScript environment. So even if a small or any other suggestion also can be helpful.

So pls anybody help me out here...

Regards

Dev

Comment: Show the exact code. There could be some syntax errors. Also on which browser(s) you tried. Because IE needs very strict syntax including ";" whereas Chrome can correct it automatically

Comment: Hiii hop,I am using firefox for testing my application and the line which i am using for navigation is- 'window.navigate("full url of my jsp")'...As I told before it is working in eclipse browser but not working either in firefox or in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.navigate()` is an IE specific implementation and its not a standard way of doing it. It will not work on all browsers.

Use `window.location.href` instead

Instead of `window.navigate("my jsp path in eclipse");` ,

Use `window.location.href = "my jsp path in eclipse";`